# Can I post on Facebook bold text with PHP SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, bold

I have this function:

```
public function postToFacebookWall($title, $uri, $desc, $msg = null, $pic = null, $caption = null, $action_name = null, $action_link = null, $uid = 'me') {
    try {
        $data = array(
            'name' => $title,
            'link' => $uri,
            'description' => $desc            
        );

        if ($pic) {
            $data['picture'] = $pic;
        }

        if ($caption) {
            $data['message'] = $caption;
        }

        if ($action_name) {
            $data['actions'] = json_encode(array('name' => $action_name, 'link' => $action_link));
        }

        App::Facebook()->api("/$uid/feed", "post", $data);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

It posts a text and a link below. Can I somehow tell Facebook to make the text to be bold? I would like to make my caption bold, but I do not know how. If I put it inside  or  tags, then on Facebook I see texts like:

```
<strong>This is my text</strong>

<b>This is my text</b>
```

instead of making the text to be bold. How can I make my text to be bold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible. Markup text is only available for Facebook Notes and documents in Facebook Groups.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, you have confirmed my hyphothesys.